# Unknown interface eth0 even though `ethtool eth0` shows info

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux

I am running kali linux on a virtual machine (VM). I started the machine today and noticed that the interface eth0 is missing.

So I tried `ifup eth0` to start it, but got output: `unknown interface eth0`.

But if I execute `ethtool eth0` then I get this output:

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: d
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason of this error is that here, `eth0` means two different things:

- either the actual interface name, as seen by the kernel, *iproute2* tools, *ethtool*, *dhclient*, etc. which does exist,
- or the [interface](https://manpages.debian.org/ifupdown/interfaces.5) configuration in the [*ifupdown*](https://packages.debian.org/stable/ifupdown) tools, pointing to the actual interface name. Here, if `eth0` was never defined in the configuration, then it's not known *by ifup*: that's the error message.

  An easy way to reproduce this error:

  ```
  # ip link add name veth5 type veth peer name veth6
  # ethtool veth5
  Settings for veth5:
      Supported ports: [ ]
  [...]
      Link detected: no
  # ifup veth5
  ifup: unknown interface veth5
  ```

So the interface is not missing. the *ifupdown* tool has not been configured to use it.

For your case, you could add at the end of `/etc/network/interfaces` (or in a separate file for example `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0` if the `interfaces` file includes the `interfaces.d` directory in its config) these two lines:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

To have the *ifupdown* tools and so the `ifup` command know about it and configure it with DHCP at boot. I have no idea why this wasn't in place before.

In my previous fake example where I added likewise `veth5`'s definition (on Debian 9):

```
# ifup -a
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/veth5/1e:96:59:c3:e4:0c
Sending on   LPF/veth5/1e:96:59:c3:e4:0c
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on veth5 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
```

Comment: I added a file named eth0 under /etc/network/interfaces.d/ folder and I configured it as static IP address. I restarted networking service but sudo ifup eth0 again give the same error. Why? ethtool shows that eth0 exists.

Comment: @hophop Use `ifup -v eth0` and `ifdown -v eth0`: debug information will tell you where it fails. Usually it's when there's a discrepancy between the real state and the ifupdown state: eg trying to add an address on an interface where the address was already added => error.

Comment: @hophop this could also be because the condition I wrote in the answer is not met: " if the interfaces file includes the interfaces.d directory in its config". If you still can't find, this will have to be in a new Q/A.

Comment: Actually I did create my own file under /etc/network/interfaces.d/ named as eth0 and configure it with dhcp, gateway etc. However, it does not work and gives the same error too. Therefore, I am opening a new question soon about that topic. Thanks.

Comment: @hophop You'd better dump really ALL of your configuration files: `interfaces` and `interfaces.d/*`. Along with `ip -br link; ip -br address`. AND the result of `ifup -v eth0`.

Comment: I did your advice and dumped and reorganize all interfaces and this time used allow-hotplug option for interfaces(since I am using USB modem) and everyting seem ok now.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by executing the command `dhclient`

[dhclient - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol Client](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient)

The Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client, dhclient, provides a means for configuring one or more network interfaces using the Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol, BOOTP protocol, or if these protocols fail, by statically assigning an address.

...

The names of the network interfaces that dhclient should attempt to configure may be specified on the command line. **If no interface names are specified on the command line** dhclient will normally identify all network interfaces, eliminating non-broadcast interfaces if possible, and attempt to configure each interface.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide an example of the command arguments you ran?

Comment: @idolize, sorry, too long ago. Can't remember if I used any arguments.

Comment: sudo dhclient -v eth0 will bring the ethernet up and get an IP address - sharing for the next person trying to figure out why ubuntu server won't bring up the network on fresh install / boot.